# In Gamemaker Studio 2 how can I find out in code whether the platform is HTML5 or not?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I want to be able to run or not run code depending on which platform I am building for. 
Some code should only run for the HTML5 platform. 
How can I found out whether the platform being run is HTML5 inside my gamemaker events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer thanks to: Charanor.
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152719/in-gamemaker-studio-2-how-can-i-find-out-in-code-whether-the-platform-is-html5-o

You can check what browser the game is currently being run in with the os_browser constant. If the game is not being run in a browser the constant will be browser_not_a_browser. So to check if it is being run in a browser simply do:

```
if os_browser != browser_not_a_browser {
     // Being run in a browser
}
```